# Nodejs json api not posting/creating name property into mongodb

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, schema, categories

I'm creating a simple shopping list with categories api using nodejs/express and mongodb with mongoose, However when post/create a new category in the db using the categories post route for some reason it's not inserting the category name and thus returning the category name property undefined.

When trying to create new item using the items post route It's returning an empty object. I've been stuck on this for awhile now.

I'm a beginner so any help would be highly appreciated, You can find the project zip file [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lsz59yfvfh1463g/shop_api.zip?dl=0) on dropbox.

Below is the index.js code:

```
var express = require("express"),
     app = express(),
     bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
     mongoose   = require("mongoose"),
     mongodb = require("mongodb"),
     ejs = require("ejs"),
     engine = require("ejs-mate"),
     port = process.env.PORT,
     ip = process.env.ip;


//using body parser
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
//mongoose database connection
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/shop", { useMongoClient: true });

mongoose.Promise = Promise;

//Category schema
var catSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String
    },
   items: [{
           type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
           ref: "Item"
        }]
});
var Category = mongoose.model("Category", catSchema);

app.post("/api/categories", function(req, res){
    Category.create(req.body)
    .then(function(newCategory){

        res.send(newCategory);
        console.log(newCategory.name);
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        res.send(err);
    });

});


app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("App is running on port: "+ port);
});
```

Comment: Please post a minimal amount of code needed to reproduce the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks for your response @FINDarkside I added the code in one file with just the Category schema,  and updated the post with it.

Comment: Have you checked that req.body isn't just empty object?

Comment: Hmmm, Thank you so much I've retested this using an html form instead of POSTMAN and it seems to be working fine, I wonder why it is not behaving the same way using postman and why is it sending an empty object when using postman and not the form.
Again thank you so much for your help as I mentioned, I'm a beginner and still learning and having a Daaa moment :)

Comment: You have probably configured postman wrong. You could just use console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body) to see what postman does send.

Comment: Thank you for your help, you're a life saver I've been stuck on this for awhile. I removed postman and reinstalled it and it works like a charm now. again I can't thank you enough for taking the time to help me with this!!

Comment: No problem! Good luck with your project!